# Find length of given curve $\rm r=a \ cos^4(\frac{t}{4})$

Tags: calculus, geometry

> Find length of given curve $\rm r=a\ cos^4\left(\frac{t}{4}\right)$

I know that if we have parametric form $r(t)$ of curve then length of arc in $[a,b]$ is :

$$s=\int_a ^b |r^\prime(t)|dt$$

**My work/question(s) :**

Writing in polar form I can find $r^\prime(t)$ but how find $a,b$ in given formula? We don't want just length of arc we want length of all curve.

Comment: I think the given curve equation is in polar coordinates, so$\\ s = \displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{r(t)^2 + r'(t)^2 } dt $

Comment: @Calmdownandhavesometea Why it's in polar?

Comment: Because otherwise, it has no meaning.